# Is there any way to terminate a kernel on AMD GPU with OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, amd-gpu

Recently, I wrote OpenCL program to use AMD GPUs. However, as I'm new to this, some problems I cannot detect directly will cause launched kernel dead, and `clinfo` also displays nothing in this condition. Is there any method to kill a running kernel on AMD GPU? Each time kernel is dead, rebooting is what I depend on to fix it for now.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way to stop a kernel which has begun executing. You should write your kernels so that they stop predictably - i.e. don't use infinite loops, just repeatedly enqueue the kernels from the host instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! but, I don't think it is the root cause. After all there is no infinite loops, if condition is also quite simple.

Comment: @user9180998 could you add the kernel code to your question so we can look through it?

Answer (score 0):

One thing i know can hang some AMD GPUs, is having a barrier that's only executed by **some** work-items of a workgroup. Note that this is not a bug in the GPU, the OpenCL specification explicitly says this about barrier():

> This function must be encountered by all work-items in a work-group executing the kernel.

So either all, or none of the work items must encounter a barrier. If only some do, your program can hang on the GPU. So i'd check the OpenCL code for things like this:

```
if (localmem[i] > 0) {
   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

You could also try using [Oclgrind](https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind) on your code, it's an OpenCL GPU emulator that's useful to find problems in OpenCL code.

Comment: Oh I'm pretty much sure that it is not caused by barrier, as commenting barrier  cannot solve this problem. By the way, does illegal memory access will cause such situation? or only segment fault will be triggered? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "does illegal memory access" << it's possible, but probably depends on hardware. Some hardware might handle it properly, some not.

Comment: ... also, illegal memory access is something that Oclgrind will catch, so you should try it.